# Fix and flexible width divs next to each other

Tags: html, css, width

I have 3 divs in the header. On the sides the width is fix, but the center div fills the remaining width.

It works on bigger screens, but under 630px, it not works. I found this great method at http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail, but it's not works for me.

Here is my code, what is very simple:

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="content">CENTER</div>
    <div id="left">LEFT</div>
    <div id="right">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
    padding:0 150px 0 250px;
}

#left {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin-left:-100%;
    background:red;
    width:250px;
    right:250px;
}

#right {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin-right:-100%;
    width:150px;
    background:pink;
}

#content {
    width:100%;
    background:green;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
```

I spent hours with it to find the problem, but I don't know what's wrong. My online example available at http://jsfiddle.net/t6vbfxpx/2/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

I saw your example code on jsFiddle.
 `#left` and `#right` have a relative position which is why they shift to the next line when the width is decreased below 630px.

Comment: They have relative position.

Comment: that's what I am saying.

Comment: without relative position same happens